# How to send random proxy in selenium for each url without opening Chrome window again and again

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy

This code opening new Chrome window for each url iteration and if i use WebDriver instance outside the loop then this not sending random proxy for each url iteration

1. i want to send random proxy for each url in these lines

```
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")
print(f"Using proxy: {proxy} for URL: {url}")
```

2. i don't want to open webdriver.Chrome window again and again

proxyscrape_premium_http_proxies.txt

```
38.162.7.130:3128
38.162.15.189:3128
38.162.5.127:3128
38.162.18.151:3128
```

urls.txt

```
https://myexternalip.com/raw
https://2ip.io
http://httpbin.org/ip
https://ipv4.webshare.io
```

app.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import random

def rand_proxy():
    with open('proxyscrape_premium_http_proxies.txt', 'r') as file:
        product_names = file.read().splitlines()
        return random.choice(product_names)


with open('urls.txt', 'r') as file:
    urls = file.readlines()

for url in urls:
    proxy = rand_proxy()
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    url = url.strip()
    driver.get(url)

    print(f"Using proxy: {proxy} for URL: {url}")
time.sleep(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing proxy settings in the middle of a browser session, you can use https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase with Wire Mode (`wire=True`).

(Note that the SeleniumBase `driver` includes both the standard `driver` methods, plus new ones.)

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(wire=True)
try:
    driver.get("https://ipinfo.io/")
    driver.sleep(6)
    driver.set_wire_proxy("35.185.196.38:3128")
    driver.get("https://ipinfo.io/")
    driver.sleep(6)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

For picking a random item in a list, use `random.choice(LIST)`:

```py
import random

my_list = ["123", "456", "789"]
print(random.choice(my_list))
```

Comment: I don't think it's a best idea because i have 1k+ proxy and 50k+ urls